# Zero-inflated negative binomial mixed-effects model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

Is there such a package that provides for zero-inflated negative binomial mixed-effects model estimation in R?

By that I mean:

- Zero-inflation where you can specify the binomial model for zero inflation, like in function zeroinfl in package pscl:

  ```
  zeroinfl(y~X|Z, dist = "negbin")
  ```

  where Z is the formula for the zero inflation model;
- Negative binomial distribution for the count part of the model;
- Random effects specified similar to function lmer of package lme4.

I understand glmmADMB can do all that, except the formula for zero inflation cannot be specified (it is just an intercept, i.e. Z is just 1). But are there any other packages that can do it all?

I will be very thankful for your help!

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I think glmmADMB is what I want, but I can't get it running.

Comment: I'm wondering whether or not the [ZIM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZIM/) or [aod](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aod/index.html) packages can do what you want to do?

Comment: As an update, the [glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html) package by Ben Bolker supports a zero-inflated generalized linear mixed
model (ZIGLMM).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the package you need: glmmADMB. 
I downloaded it here: http://otter-rsch.com/admbre/examples/glmmadmb/glmmADMB.html

But I still had some problems to get it to run, so I followed the instructions provided in this link and now it works fine http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this package only allows the fitting of a constant term for the zero-inflation part of the model.

Answer (score 1):

The [pscl](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i08/paper) package provides for a zero inflated Poisson model. I don't think that it can do a negative binomial model, but it might be a place to start. The linked JSS article also discusses related packages, which may lead you to what you're looking for.

Comment: The pscl package does (now) allow negative binomial models by using `zeroinfl(..., dist = "negbin", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to look at the [aster package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aster/index.html). Aster models allow joint analysis of multiple variables that have different probability distributions, and recently have been updated to allow for [random effects](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1380804816). They were designed for life history analysis and will work in situations where you can split your response into distinct parts with different distributions, (e.g. survival = Bernoulli, reproduction = Poisson). They can handle "zero-inflation" by modeling the majority of zeroes as bernoulli, and the remainder of the response as negative binomial.

You'll find plenty of documentation here:

http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/aster/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of packages available. This link might be helpful:
https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-066/RJ-2017-066.pdf